# Spring Authentication Server is Not Adding OAuth Authentication Providers

Tags: spring-authorization-server

I am trying to configure Spring Authorization Server (version 1.1.0, Boot 3.1.0), but it's not working the way I think the docs suggest.  When making a request to the authorization endpoint, the `OAuth2AuthorizationEndpointFilter` is denying authorization because it does not have a provider for the `OAuth2AuthorizationCodeRequestAuthenticationToken`.  The token does have an authenticated `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken` inside of it with the correct `GrantedAuthorities`, so the upstream part of authentication seems to be working.  But the `OAuth2AuthorizationCodeRequestAuthenticationConverter` turns it into the OAuth specific token.

The `AuthenticationManager` being used is the main one for the rest of the app, which has only Dao and RememberMe providers. I try to add the `OAuth2AuthorizationCodeRequestAuthenticationProvider` via the configurer, as seen in the code below, but it's not there when I set a breakpoint.

Here is my security config (the comments are the XML configuration for the previous Spring Security OAuth 2 which was working fine - but not in Boot 3.1.0).

```
    /*
    <http pattern="/oauth/**" auto-config="true" entry-point-ref="oauthLoginEntryPoint" use-expressions="true" create-session="always">
        <csrf disabled="false"/>
        <intercept-url pattern="/oauth/authorize" access="hasRole('ROLE_MEMBER')" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/oauth/**" access="permitAll"/>

        <!-- UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter -->
        <form-login default-target-url="/oauth/authorize"  
                    login-processing-url="/oauth/do_login"
                    authentication-failure-url="/oauth/login?failure=true"
                    authentication-success-handler-ref="oauthAuthenticationSuccessHandler"
                    username-parameter="username"
                    password-parameter="password" />
    </http>
     */
    @Bean
    @Order(103)
    public SecurityFilterChain oauthFilterChain(HttpSecurity http, 
                                                AuthenticationManager authenticationManager,
                                                JdbcRegisteredClientRepository registeredClientRepository,
                                                OAuth2TokenGenerator<?> tokenGenerator,
                                                OAuth2AuthorizationCodeRequestAuthenticationProvider authorizationCodeRequestAuthenticationProvider) 
                                throws Exception
    {
        http
            .securityMatcher("/oauth/**")
            .authorizeHttpRequests(auth -> auth
                .requestMatchers("/oauth/authorize").hasRole("MEMBER")
                .requestMatchers("/oauth/**").permitAll()
            )
            .sessionManagement(session -> session
                .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.ALWAYS)
                .sessionFixation(c -> c.none())  // FIXME turn it back on 
            )
            .authenticationManager(authenticationManager)
            .formLogin(form -> form
                .successForwardUrl("/oauth/authorize")
                .loginProcessingUrl("/oauth/do_login")
                .failureUrl("/oauth/login?failure=true")
                .successHandler(oauthAuthenticationSuccessHandler())
                .usernameParameter("username")
                .passwordParameter("password")
                .loginPage(OAUTH_LOGIN_VIEW_NAME)
            )
            .exceptionHandling(exception -> exception.authenticationEntryPoint(oauthLoginEntryPoint()))
            .csrf(withDefaults())
            ;
        
        //OAuth2AuthorizationServerConfiguration.applyDefaultSecurity(http);
        OAuth2AuthorizationServerConfigurer authorizationServerConfigurer = new OAuth2AuthorizationServerConfigurer();
        http.apply(authorizationServerConfigurer);
        authorizationServerConfigurer
            .registeredClientRepository(registeredClientRepository) 
            .tokenGenerator(tokenGenerator) 
            .clientAuthentication(clientAuthentication -> clientAuthentication
                    .authenticationProvider(authorizationCodeRequestAuthenticationProvider)
            )  
            .authorizationEndpoint(authorizationEndpoint -> authorizationEndpoint
                    .authenticationProvider(authorizationCodeRequestAuthenticationProvider)
            )    
            .tokenEndpoint(tokenEndpoint -> { })    
        ;
       
        return http.build();
        
    }
    
    /*
    <!--  this forces the redirect back to /oauth/authorize to be https -->
    <beans:bean id="oauthAuthenticationSuccessHandler" class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler">
        <beans:property name="redirectStrategy">
            <beans:bean class="com.hatchbaby.service.security.ForceHttpsRedirectStrategy">
                <beans:property name="forceHttps" value="${oauth.https.login}"/>
            </beans:bean>
        </beans:property>
    </beans:bean>
     */
    @Bean
    public SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler  oauthAuthenticationSuccessHandler()
    {
        SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler ash = new SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler();
        ForceHttpsRedirectStrategy rs = new ForceHttpsRedirectStrategy();
        rs.setForceHttps(forceHttps);
        ash.setRedirectStrategy(rs);
        return ash;
    }
    
    @Bean
    public LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint oauthLoginEntryPoint()
    {
        LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint ep = new LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint(OAUTH_LOGIN_VIEW_NAME);
        ep.setForceHttps(forceHttps);
        return ep;
    }

    @Bean
    public JdbcRegisteredClientRepository registeredClientRepository(JdbcOperations jdbcOperations)
    {
        JdbcRegisteredClientRepository repo = new JdbcRegisteredClientRepository(jdbcOperations);
        return repo;
    }
    
    @Bean
    public OAuth2TokenGenerator<?> tokenGenerator(JWKSource<SecurityContext> jwkSource) 
    {
        JwtEncoder jwtEncoder = new NimbusJwtEncoder(jwkSource);
        JwtGenerator jwtGenerator = new JwtGenerator(jwtEncoder);
        OAuth2AccessTokenGenerator accessTokenGenerator = new OAuth2AccessTokenGenerator();
        OAuth2RefreshTokenGenerator refreshTokenGenerator = new OAuth2RefreshTokenGenerator();
        return new DelegatingOAuth2TokenGenerator(
                jwtGenerator, accessTokenGenerator, refreshTokenGenerator);
    }
    
    @Bean 
    public JWKSource<SecurityContext> jwkSource() {
        KeyPair keyPair = generateRsaKey();
        RSAPublicKey publicKey = (RSAPublicKey) keyPair.getPublic();
        RSAPrivateKey privateKey = (RSAPrivateKey) keyPair.getPrivate();
        RSAKey rsaKey = new RSAKey.Builder(publicKey)
                .privateKey(privateKey)
                .keyID(UUID.randomUUID().toString())
                .build();
        JWKSet jwkSet = new JWKSet(rsaKey);
        return new ImmutableJWKSet<>(jwkSet);
    }

    private static KeyPair generateRsaKey() { 
        KeyPair keyPair;
        try {
            KeyPairGenerator keyPairGenerator = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA");
            keyPairGenerator.initialize(2048);
            keyPair = keyPairGenerator.generateKeyPair();
        }
        catch (Exception ex) {
            throw new IllegalStateException(ex);
        }
        return keyPair;
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthorizationServerSettings authorizationServerSettings()
    {
        AuthorizationServerSettings.Builder builder = AuthorizationServerSettings.builder()
                .authorizationEndpoint("/oauth/authorize")
                .tokenEndpoint("/oauth/token")
        ;
        
        return builder.build();
    }
    
    @Bean
    public OAuth2AuthorizationCodeRequestAuthenticationProvider oAuth2AuthorizationCodeRequestAuthenticationProvider(
            RegisteredClientRepository registeredClientRepository,
            OAuth2AuthorizationService authorizationService, 
            OAuth2AuthorizationConsentService authorizationConsentService)
    {
        return new OAuth2AuthorizationCodeRequestAuthenticationProvider(registeredClientRepository, authorizationService, authorizationConsentService);
    }
    
    @Bean
    public OAuth2AuthorizationService oauth2AuthorizationService()
    {
        // FIXME use jdbc
        //JdbcOAuth2AuthorizationService auth =  new JdbcOAuth2AuthorizationService();
        var auth = new InMemoryOAuth2AuthorizationService();
        return auth;
    }
    
    @Bean
    public OAuth2AuthorizationConsentService oauth2AuthorizationConsentService()
    {
        // FIXME not in memory
        var auth = new InMemoryOAuth2AuthorizationConsentService();
        return auth;
    }
```

Any help on getting that `authorizationCodeRequestAuthenticationProvider` to show up in the `AuthenicationManager`?

Comment: This might be normal but is the Auth request really going to <http> and not <https> ?  Maybe some calls don't need to be encrypted but I wonder if something is there.

Comment: @easleyfixed if you are referring to the "forceHttps" parameter, that's only ever false on our local dev servers so we can run tests without running https.  In prod it's "true"

Comment: ok making sure it was the dev build and not production, very good.  There are some other mentions of http but maybe its more like the link than the protocol, but thanks for clearing that up.

Comment: Just to make sure, are you attempting to upgrade a legacy spring-security-oauth project to Spring Boot 3.1? Are you aware that the spring-security-oauth project is [end-of-life](https://spring.io/blog/2020/05/07/end-of-life-for-spring-security-oauth) and Spring Authorization Server is not a drop-in replacement?

Comment: Of course, if it were drop-in I'd be done a long time ago!! :-) I have the old XML there as a guide to what I need to set up to reproduce the functionality that I've had for ~6-7 years.

Comment: Very true. Ok, so I would recommend building a completely new application on Spring Authorization Server and slowly add back your functionality piece by piece. Since it's not a drop-in replacement, the strategy of trying to start with everything you had before from a configuration perspective and figure out what is going wrong feels like it makes things more difficult than they need to be. It seems just as hard for me to "guess" what's wrong with your setup as it is for you, which is a sign that you need to simplify it first. Does that help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I was unable to get the DSL to add the authentication providers that I wanted. I kept adding them to the DSL because I felt like I "should".

```
    @Bean
    @Order(103)
    public SecurityFilterChain oauthFilterChain(HttpSecurity http, 
                                                AuthenticationManager authenticationManager,
                                                JdbcRegisteredClientRepository registeredClientRepository,
                                                OAuth2AuthorizationCodeRequestAuthenticationProvider authorizationCodeRequestAuthenticationProvider,
                                                OAuth2AuthorizationCodeAuthenticationProvider oauth2AuthorizationCodeAuthenticationProvider,
                                                OAuth2RefreshTokenAuthenticationProvider oauth2RefreshTokenAuthenticationProvider,
                                                OAuth2ClientCredentialsAuthenticationProvider oauth2ClientCredentialsAuthenticationProvider,
                                                ClientSecretAuthenticationProvider clientSecretAuthenticationProvider
                    )   throws Exception
    {
        http
            .securityMatcher("/oauth/**")
            .authorizeHttpRequests(auth -> auth
                .requestMatchers("/oauth/authorize").hasRole("MEMBER")
                .requestMatchers("/oauth/**").permitAll()
            )
            .sessionManagement(session -> session
                .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.ALWAYS)
                .sessionFixation(c -> c.none())  // FIXME turn it back on 
            )
            .authenticationManager(authenticationManager)
            .formLogin(form -> form
                .successForwardUrl("/oauth/authorize")
                .loginProcessingUrl("/oauth/do_login")
                .failureUrl("/oauth/login?failure=true")
                .successHandler(oauthAuthenticationSuccessHandler())
                .usernameParameter("username")
                .passwordParameter("password")
                .loginPage(OAUTH_LOGIN_VIEW_NAME)
            )
            .exceptionHandling(exception -> exception.authenticationEntryPoint(oauthLoginEntryPoint()))
            .csrf(c -> c.ignoringRequestMatchers("/oauth/token"))
            ;
        
        OAuth2AuthorizationServerConfigurer authorizationServerConfigurer = new OAuth2AuthorizationServerConfigurer();
        http.apply(authorizationServerConfigurer);
        authorizationServerConfigurer
            .registeredClientRepository(registeredClientRepository) 
            .tokenGenerator(tokenGenerator()) 
            .clientAuthentication(clientAuthentication -> clientAuthentication
                    .authenticationProvider(authorizationCodeRequestAuthenticationProvider)
            )  
            .authorizationEndpoint(authorizationEndpoint -> authorizationEndpoint
                    .authenticationProvider(authorizationCodeRequestAuthenticationProvider)
            )    
            .tokenEndpoint(tokenEndpoint -> tokenEndpoint
                    .authenticationProvider(oauth2AuthorizationCodeAuthenticationProvider)
                    .authenticationProvider(oauth2RefreshTokenAuthenticationProvider)
                    .authenticationProvider(oauth2ClientCredentialsAuthenticationProvider)
                    .authenticationProvider(clientSecretAuthenticationProvider)
            )    
        ;
       
        return http.build();
        
    }
```

But in order to make it work, I had to go back to the main `AuthenticationManager` and update it:

```
    @Bean(name = {BeanIds.AUTHENTICATION_MANAGER, "authenticationManager"})
    @Primary
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManager(
            OAuth2AuthorizationCodeRequestAuthenticationProvider oauth2AuthorizationCodeRequestAuthenticationProvider,
            OAuth2AuthorizationCodeAuthenticationProvider oauth2AuthorizationCodeAuthenticationProvider,
            OAuth2RefreshTokenAuthenticationProvider oauth2RefreshTokenAuthenticationProvider,
            OAuth2ClientCredentialsAuthenticationProvider oauth2ClientCredentialsAuthenticationProvider,
            ClientSecretAuthenticationProvider clientSecretAuthenticationProvider,
            OauthSecretKeySource keySource,
            LegacyOauthAuthenticationProvider legacyOauthAuthenticationProvider
        )
    {
        // FIXME I don't like having to add the whole Oauth guys here
        List<AuthenticationProvider> aps = List.of(
                authProvider(),
                rememberMeAuthenticationProvider(),
                oauth2AuthorizationCodeRequestAuthenticationProvider,
                oauth2AuthorizationCodeAuthenticationProvider,
                oauth2RefreshTokenAuthenticationProvider,
                oauth2ClientCredentialsAuthenticationProvider,
                clientSecretAuthenticationProvider,
                legacyOauthAuthenticationProvider,
                jwtAuthenticationProvider(keySource)
        );
        ProviderManager pm = new ProviderManager(aps);
        return pm;
    }
```

So the Oauth guys are added to the `AuthenticationManager` for everyone, while I was hoping they'd be limited to that `SecurityFilterChain`.  Not ideal, but it's working.